# React JS: onClick not working; cant put a "line-through" display property using onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Why is my display 'line-through' on my paragraph doesn't display? Im pretty sure Im missing something big here, and thats my only knowledge on react for now, so please help me get an idea logic. I apologized my ignorance about this simple problem.

```
const [strike, isStrike] = React.useState(false);
```

I set strike state into true here; (Am I right?)

```
const done = () => {
   isStrike(strike);
};

const s = {
  textDecoration: isDone ? "line-through" : "none",
};
```

I set the isDone prop and strike var through {strike && isDone} and I called the done function into onClick.

```
return (
    <div className="container-item" style={s} >
      <p> {title} </p>
      {strike && isDone}
      <button onClick={done} > Done</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all where you define the `isDone`? And you have lots of errors in your code. And you can't declare `{strike && isDone}` as a child. It will throw error. Below is the working code.

And, I think `isStrike` still getting the initial false the way you define the `done` function. Why don't you just make `isStrike(!strike)`. Hope this will solve the issue.

```
const [strike, isStrike] = useState(false);
const done = () => {
   isStrike(!strike)
}
const s = {
   textDecoration: strike ? "line-through" : "none",
};
return (
  <div className="container-item" style={s} >
    <p> Hello, Title </p>
    <button onClick={done} > Done</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This works sir! Thank you. I also have another code too, and its works the same but this is more optimized or less code than mine. Can I ask you if you dont mind, what is {strike && isDone} (what do you call this) for? For me, its a indication that, strike and isDone is true.

Comment: The isDone is in another module component or module. It is a boolean: const rawList [ {id: 1, title: Do this, isDone: false}, that is what isDone is. It is set to false so when I hit a button, the isDone will become true, but I think you cant change the original value there

Comment: @Deny You can check the link for a more convenient solution. There I imported `isDone` from separate components and passed `isDone` as a `props`. 
Solution Code[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-solution-pkzcf). Hope this might help you now with your code.

Comment: I checked the link you shared, its cool. Thanks you! The const [strike, setIsStrike] = useState(props.doneOrNot), does it mean that your setting the useState(props.doneOrNot) to first arg which is strike?

Comment: Yes. That's the initial value for the strike.

Comment: Thanks for helping sir!

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead and give this code a try, champion.

```
const [textDecorationType, setTextDecorationType] = React.useState(false);
return (
<div className="container-item">
<p className={`text-decoration:${textDecorationType ? 'line-through' :''}`}> 
{title}</p>
<button onClick={() => setTextDecorationType(!textDecorationType)}>
Done</button></div>);
```

Comment: Uhm, theres an error right here bro, <p className={`text-decoration:${textDecorationType ? 'line-through' :''}`}>,   unexpected token, I guess its bcoz of a wrong syntax? Btw, thank you for helping! This is some pretty good idea

Comment: You are welcome. It is probably the missing `` anyways I am glad to see that you've solved it with a previous answer. Keep coding bro, it is always fun!

Comment: Im not having fun in coding, I get frustrated. Even just like this simple problem, I just cant solve.